# deploy picklists with mavensmate?

Tags: picklist, mavensmate

Is there a way to deploy picklists from a dev org to a sandbox with mavensmate? If not, what is a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

MavensMate will be able to deploy picklists from dev to sandbox, because it is built on top of the Salesforce Metadata API.

An alternative from my team is [Gearset](https://gearset.com). Gearset will be able to deploy that picklist for you in about 10 clicks from first visiting our website to a finished deployment. The screenshot below shows what our user interface looks like

We offer a full 30-day free trial and don't require you to install anything in your org so no lock in.

[image: Picklist deployment with Gearset]

Comment: Does Gearset make the picklist values consistent i.e. add new ones and remove spurious extra ones or does it only add the new ones?

Comment: Keeps them consistent

Comment: I actually had some deletions just out of sight in that view, but they had client names in them so I purposefully scrolled them out of view!